# Why my links are not displaying at center?

Tags: html, css

i am learning html css,  now i want to create nav bar as my task. so when am trying to create horizontal nav bar, my menus are not showing at the center of my nav bar div ? why its attached with top corner ? i want them at center from top and bottom here is my code correct my mistake

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 50%;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add `text-align:center` on `ul`

Comment: why my links are attached with top border ?

Comment: add `inline-block` on `li`

Comment: oh yes thats work now, i will understand what is inline and inline-block. while creating nav bar do i need to style li or <a> ? where i have to apply styles most of the time ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do, you can use `flex` and tweak your code if needed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
}

ul {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li> <a href="">About Us</a></li>
  <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no doubt your code will work fine but am asking where is my mistake ? why my margin-top not working ? why its attached with top border

Comment: Margin-top is working, if you take that out you can see the differences. in your case it is `inline` and by default it will used as a column than row.

Comment: Because you used `display: inline` on that element. `When it comes to margins and padding, browsers treat inline elements differently. You can add space to the left and right on an inline element, but you cannot add height to the top or bottom padding or margin of an inline element.`

Answer (score 0):

I added **display:inline-block** to both li and ul and **text-align:center** to nav.
and that will make **margin-top** works.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  text-align: center
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li> <a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

check here: https://jsfiddle.net/w3hn1L95/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a

```css
test-align: center;
```

to your `ul` element in css.